# Republish Android app after updating the privacy ploicy

Tags: android, google-play

My recently uploaded version of an existing app on Google Play wasn't published since it didn't meet certain privacy policy criteria . Now, I've updated the privacy policy on my website; however how do I re-submit the app so that the new version goes live?

Answer (score 3):

With [millions of emails sent by Google warning developers](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/#write) you are definitely not alone. Before resubmitting, update your privacy policy correctly, you do want to make sure you submit it with the necessary changes.

You say you've updated your privacy policy on your site, however Google requires the privacy policy to be there compliant in the Google Play store as well. That's likely where you need to resubmit.

**To add it to the [Store Listing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2519872):**

1. Log into your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/)
2. Next, select **All Applications** and select the application whose privacy policy you'd like to edit.
3. After that, select **Store Listing**.
4. Then, scroll to the section marked **Privacy Policy** and enter the URL where you have the privacy policy hosted online.
5. Lastly, be sure to click **Save or update**.

**More information about how to write your privacy policy for the Play Store**

The best way to comply is to have a readable, understandable and easily accessible privacy policy, which at a minimum informs users about:

- *who you are (identity and contact details)*,
- *what precise categories of personal data the app wants to collect and process*,
- *why the data processing is necessary (for what precise purposes)*,
- *whether data will be disclosed to third parties (not just a generic but a specific description to whom the data will be disclosed)*,
- *what rights users have, in terms of withdrawal of consent and deletion of data*.

**With that said, if you do decide to create your own policy, here are some tips:**

1. *Outline which dangerous/sensitive permissions you request*
2. *Outline any other user data you collect, for instance advertisement services!*
3. *Describe what purpose they serve and use them only for that purpose*
4. Information about the site/app owner.
5. The kind of data being collected and how it is collected.
6. The purpose of the data collection (i.e. analytics, email marketing).
7. Any third parties that have access to the information and through which means (widgets and integrations).
8. The rights of users regarding their data (i.e. the ability to request to see the data, to rectify, erase, or block).
9. The process for notifying users and visitors regarding material changes to the privacy policy.
10. Effective date of the privacy policy.

(p.s I work on a tool called iubenda that helps with the generation of a privacy policy - [link](http://iubenda.com/mobile))